# How do you change an element innerText without changing its children

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child, innertext

I have an html element like:

```
<div id="el1">Change only me<div>but not me</div></div>
```

but I only wanna change the first text and leave the child div as it is

```js
document.getElementById("el1").innerText = "changed!"
```

```html
<div id="el1">Change only me<div>but not me</div></div>
```

Comment: you can wrap the text you want to change using a span and then target the span element and change its innerText

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById("el1").childNodes[0].textContent = "changed";
```

```html
<div id="el1">Change only me<div>but not me</div></div>
```